# How to specify application / domain name in a deployable zip?

Tags: mule

I am building a Mule domain using Maven which works fine, except the zip file it creates is named MyDomain-1.0.0.0.zip

Mule (community edition) will bring up this domain with a domain name of MyDomain-1.0.0.0 when deployed.

I want the name to be MyDomain. I cannot find a way of specifying the domain name which is used - it seems Mule always uses the zip file name.

The reason i want to do this is because the applications in the domain are coded to use MyDomain, and obviously fail if the domain isnt named as such.

When running in AnyPoint, the domain is named after the project name, and I dont want to have to change the project name in Anypoint to include the version number.

Is this possible please? the only way round it ive found is to rename the zip file to MyDomain.zip, which I dont want to do since I want releases to have unique zip filenames (but keep the same domain name)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `finalName` child tag of `build` i.e:

```
<build>
    <finalName>myapp</finalName>
</build>
```

Comment: ... And this actually does answer the question but using finalName in maven breaks the way you can let maven handle versioning for the mule runtime. some app for example might use myDomain-1.0.0 and others myDomain-2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Use the domain *including* the version. It would allow you to have apps run in different versions of a domain without the requirement of a turn-key switch to a new domain version.

So, create a project called 'myDomain' (you probably have that) and set in the mule-project.xml of your domain that the domain is 'myDomain-1.0.0'. This would allow the versioning of both the domains and the api referencing them to be handled by maven versioning and not force any weird and ugly things like using finalName (which forfeits all SNAPSHOT and versioning capabilities).

Also, you are now free to develop a myDomain2 and let it propagate the 'myDomain-2.0.0' domain. The reference of every app to it's domain in the pom.xml will be just as it's suppose to be. An app will just request 'myDomain-1.0.0' from the .m2 maven repo and it will find it.